# Decimal values getting truncated in Python list

Tags: python

Following is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
res = {u'salary': 28.86823689842918, u'name': u'john'}
result = {}
score_list = []

result.update(res)
if result[u'name'] == 'john':
    score_list.append(result[u'salary'])
print score_list[0]
```

Expected result in print is 
28.86823689842918
But I am getting 28.8682368984.

Can any help me to get the original value without getting truncated.

Comment: `from decimal import Decimal` and `Decimal(28.86823689842918)`

Comment: @Vidul `Decimal(28.86823689842918)` won't solve anything, it should be `Decimal('28.86823689842918')`

Comment: @vaultah _Decimal instances can be constructed from integers, strings, floats, or tuples._ (from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html))

Comment: @Vidul *If value is a float, the binary floating point value is losslessly converted to its exact decimal equivalent. This conversion can often require 53 or more digits of precision. For example, Decimal(float('1.1')) converts to Decimal('1.100000000000000088817841970012523233890533447265625').* It won't get truncated, but that's probably not the desired result.

Comment: @vaultah I agree. My comment is misleading.

Comment: `print "%0.14f"% score_list[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important point is that 28.86823689842918 is not a decimal value in Python: it is (generates) a binary floating-point value with 32 bits of precision. It has not enough precision to remember all those decimals.

The most important things are: a) how exactly did you get that number (is it a result of some calculation? I highly doubt someone has a salary that precise;), and b) what do you intend to do with it (just print it? calculate with it?...) Depending on the answers to those questions, I'll be able to recommend the best way.

For example, if you just want to print it, '28.86823689842918' is good enough. If you intend to do calculations with about 14 digits of precision with it, 28.8682368984 is good enough. If you intend it to behave as a "school" decimal number would, Decimal('28.86823689842918') is good enough.

If it is a result of some calculation, maybe the true representation is to remember the calculation itself, not its results. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is using `repr`:

```
print repr(score_list[0])
```

Comment: Hi Maroun I am getting 28.868236898429181 instead of 28.86823689842918 if I use repr()

Comment: @Madan Did you try `repr(28.86823689842918)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from decimal import Decimal

res = {u'salary': Decimal('28.86823689842918'), u'name': u'john'}
```